If computing $x$ is intractable under CDH, is distinguishing $H(x)$ from $H(t)$ intractable under DDH?
It is already shown that given the inputs $I$ and unknowns $U$, it is intractable to compute $x$, under CDH assumption.
Now, can I say that, given, H is an irreversible cryptographic hash function (e.g. SHA-512), with the same inputs and unknowns, the problem of distinguishing $H(x)$ from any $H(t)$ is also intractable under DDH assumption ?

Assuming an adversary $\mathcal{A}$ has an oracle $\mathcal{B}$ capable of distinguishing $H(x)$ from $H(t)\;\forall\, t\in Z_{q}$.
$$ \Big\vert Pr[\mathcal{B}(g, I, H(x)) = 1] - Pr[\mathcal{B}(g, I, H(t)) = 1] \Big\vert > \epsilon$$
However, the adversary cannot compute $x$ from $I$.
$H$ being a cryptographic hash function, it is infeasible to distinguish between $H(x), H(t)$ if $x$ and $t$ are both unknowns, which is violated by the assumption.
Hence, it is infeasible to distinguish between $H(x)$ from $H(t)\;\forall\, t\in Z_{q}$ given $I$, when $U$ is still unknown, because the problem of computing $H(x)$ from $I$ is intractable under CDH assumption.

Is this sufficient that in this case intractability under CDH causes decisional infeasibility? Or it is still necessary to show that DDH reduction is unnecessary.
Should I assume that the $H$ satisfies Indistinguishability property ? Or satisfying non-correlation property is sufficient?

Is $x = g^{ab}$?  If so, you need to give the Oracle $\mathcal{B}$ the inputs $g^a, g^b$ for CDH/DDH to be applicable...

Yes, that's why I pass $I$ the set of inputs to oracle $\mathcal{B}$. Here, $I = {g^{a}, g^{b}}$

It might have been helpful if you defined your terms

I have kept it as $I, U$ because if it was plain $I = {g^{a}, g^{b}}$ and $U = {a,b}$ then it is not really necessary to proof CDH. Thats why I want to generalize that given the problem is proven for $I,U$ computing $x$ is CDH, deciding whether a given $H(x)$ is the hash of $x$ computed from $I$ with unknowns $U$ is infeasible for the polynomial adversary.
